# Modify the HREF of multiple elements if it does not trail with certain text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to modify URLs in an element using js using:

```
$.each($('a'), function(i,v){
    var oldULR =  $(v).attr('href');
    var newURL = oldULR.replace('/fold/fold', '/newfolder');
    $(this).attr('href', newURL);
    
});
```

However, I am only trying to change the URL "IF" it "DOES NOT" have `add` or `delete` on the end of the URL.  I have the following URL examples:**

```
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/AAA">AAA</a>
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/AAA/add">Add new AAA</a>
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/BBB/delete">Delete BBB</a>
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/CCC/add">Add new CCC</a>
```

So I only want to change `/fold/fold` to `/newfolder` if there isn't an ending of `add` or `delete`..So my final result would look like:

```
<a href="http://example.com/newfolder/AAA">AAA</a>  <!--changed-->
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/AAA/add">Add new AAA</a> <!--no change-->
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/BBB/delete">Delete BBB</a> <!--no change-->
<a href="http://example.com/fold/fold/CCC/add">Add new CCC</a> <!--no change-->
```

Comment: Curious as to the reasons behind this !?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe use .endsWith() to check the URL's ending string?

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith

```
$.each($('a'), function(i,v){
    var oldULR =  $(v).attr('href');
    var newURL = oldULR.replace('/fold/fold', '/newfolder');
    if (!oldULR.endsWith('/add') && !oldULR.endsWith('/delete')){
        $(this).attr('href', newURL);
    }
});
```

Comment: no problem, note the polyfill, as this may not be supported in all browsers you need to support (see link I provided)

Answer (score 1):

Use a conditional statement can do this

```
$.each($('a'), function(i,v){
    var oldURL =  $(v).attr('href');
    if (!oldURL.endsWith('/add') && !oldURL.endsWith('/delete')) {
        var newURL = oldULR.replace('/fold/fold', '/newfolder');
        $(this).attr('href', newURL);        
    }
});
```

Comment: this answer and mine are essentially the same.  The reason @Asoul's answer didn't work was probably the typo in the variable name 'oldULR' he refers to 'oldURL'.  The only difference between his and mine (aside from the typo) is that he builds the new URL after the check to see if it's necessary.  And I'd say Asoul's implementation is better because of that.  I was just trying to get you working code quickly but this is the better answer.

Comment: Oops, thanks @quack, I just copy the original code, not noticed that